# How to calculate gradients on a tensor in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I want to calculate the gradient of a tensor and however, it gives error as

```
RunTimeerror: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

and here is what I am trying to code:

```
x = torch.full((2,3), 4,requires_grad=True)
y = (2*x**2+3)
y.backward()
```

And at this point, it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no summing up/reducing the loss-value , like `.sum()`
Hence the issue could be fixed by:

```
y.backward(torch.ones_like(x))
```

which performs a Jacobian-vector product with a tensor of all ones and get the gradient.